# Yammer RESTful API and cross-domain ajax calls

Tags: ajax, json, rest, jsonp, yammer

I wish to get a single thread and its comments from Yammer using the REST API. Using a standard ajax call to get the json result yields the following error:

```
XMLHttpRequest cannot load https://www.yammer.com/api/v1/messages/in_group/1072435.json.
No 'Access-Control-Allow-    Origin' header is present on the requested resource.
Origin 'http://localhost:52785' is therefore not allowed access.
```

To allow cross-domain calls I can use a jsonp result using the following code:

```
$.ajax({
    type: 'GET',
    url: "https://www.yammer.com/api/v1/messages/in_group/1072435.json",
    dataType: "jsonp",
    jsonp: false,
    success: function(data) {
        messages = data.messages;
        //do stuff with messages
    }
});
```

However, I get the following error:
    Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected token :

This occurs on parsing the json result - since I am using jsonp I would expect the result to return in the form of callFunction({json}), however I'm just getting the json. But if I go into the Network tab in Chrome and bring up the request, the request itself is successful, and I can view the json result which are correctly grouped (I can expand the messages property and see all the messages).

It seems that I can get the data, but not use it. Is there any way to prevent this error, or am I doing this wrong from the start?

Comment: were you able to get data from  yammer?

Answer (score 1):

First of all, by setting jsonp to false, you tell jQuery not to add the ?callback=[randomfunctionname] to the url. According to the jQuery documentation (https://api.jquery.com/jQuery.ajax/) it is then necessary to set the jsonpCallback property as well, because otherwise jQuery won't know which callback function to call when the wrapped JSON returns.

Secondly, to be able to use JSONP, the Yammer REST API needs to support this, because they need to wrap the JSON in the callback function you specify. Otherwise, it's just a cross-domain call to a JSON file which is not supported due to browser security restrictions. This is what you see when you make the request in Chrome and check the Network tab.

I'm not sure if Yammer supports JSONP, but at the least you should fix your request, probably by removing the jsonp:false to make it more default. If this doesn't work then probably it's the lack of support for JSONP with Yammer.